# Fatal error: Class 'Magento\TestFramework\TestCase\WebapiAbstract' not found

Tags: magento2

Hi I'm trying to cxreate an API test for my custom  module and I'm getting this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Magento\TestFramework\TestCase\WebapiAbstract' not
>   found in
>   /var/www/html/app/code/Wakanda/QuoteApi/Test/Api/CustomerQuoteTest.php
>   on line 8

```
<?php 

namespace Wakanda\QuoteApi\Test\Api;

use Magento\TestFramework\TestCase\WebapiAbstract;
use Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Request;

class CustomerQuoteTest extends WebapiAbstract
{
    public function testGetList()
    {
        $serviceInfo = [
            'rest' => [
                'resourcePath' => '',
                'httpMethod' => Request::HTTP_METHOD_GET,
            ],
        ];

        $response = $this->_webApiCall($serviceInfo);

        $this->assertArrayHasKey('search_criteria', $response);
        $this->assertArrayHasKey('item', $response);

        $this->assertTrue($response['total_count'] > 0);
        $this->assertTrue(count($response['total_count']) > 0);

        $this->assertNotNull($response['items'][0]['name']);
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing the dev folder?

In particular this file?

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/dev/tests/api-functional/framework/Magento/TestFramework/TestCase/WebapiAbstract.php

Comment: The file is there. Some of magento core tests are referencing it. I literally copied one of the tests and it still couldn't find it

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're not using the phpunit config files located in `dev/tests/api-functional`.

If you want to execute the REST API functional tests, first copy the `phpunit_rest.xml.dist` to `phpunit_rest.xml` in the directory dev/tests/api-functional, then do the same for the `install-config-mysql.php.dist` (copy to `install-config-mysql.php`)

After that try executing the api functional tests from the integration tests folder:

```
cd dev/tests/integration
 ../../../vendor/bin/phpunit -c ../api-functional/phpunit_rest.xml
```

For me this was the solution. When I tried to execute `phpunit_rest.xml` directly from the API functional testing folder, [I got this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51672014/i-can-not-run-api-functional-test-in-magento-2).